# Are two different cyclic Reed-Solomon-Codes with the same parameters equivalent?

Tags: coding-theory

While I found in many books that two Hamming-codes with the same parameters are equivalent, I could not find a similar fact as to cyclic Reed-Solomon-Codes. (I am using the definition of monomial equivalence, i.e. two codes $C, C'$ are called equivalent if there is a monomial matrix $M$ such that $ C'=CM=\{cM : c \in C\}$).
I tried to construct a counter-example of which I am not sure if it is valid:

We choose $\mathbb{F_7}$ as a field. Then e.g. $5$ and $3$ are two different $6$th roots of unity in $\mathbb{F_7}$. We may therefore construct two cyclic RS-codes of length $7$, dimension $3$ and minimal distance $4$ by the two generator polynomials
$(X-5)(X-4)(X-6)$ and $(X-3)(X-2)(X-6)$, respectively. We can easily form their generator matrices and bring them into standard form: \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 6
\end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 6
\end{pmatrix}.
This means the generator matrices of both codes have different standard forms. As far as I can see, this implies the two codes are not equivalent. I would be grateful if someone could correct me or give me hint.

Comment: What does equivalent mean to you?  As vector subspaces, the two codes are equivalent in terms of dimension, minimum distance, weight enumerators, etc. They are _not_ equivalent if equivalence is restricted to permutation of coordinates only.

Comment: I am using monomial equivalence (I forgot to mention this - I have edited the post accordingly).

Comment: So as every linear code is equivalent to a code generated by a matrix in standard form and because this standard form is unique, those two codes are not equivalent by my definition of equivalence, are they?